# roscore works normal from command line but it does not work over ssh

Tags: ros, remote-roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just recently installed ros-indigo on raspberry pi. The roscore works fine when I run it from the raspberry pi itself. But when i try to run it from my laptop through ssh i get the following error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

After termination of process rosout it restarts over and over again.

Btw sorry for my bad English. It is not my native.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209641/roscore-works-normal-from-command-line-but-it-does-not-work-over-ssh/) by [huseyin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22504/huseyin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you set your locale as specified in the install instructions? http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [huseyin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22504/huseyin/) on 2015-05-22**:
yeah you are right. Problem was in the locales i changed raspberry pi 's local. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-22**:
Glad that it's working. Please mark this answer as accepted(using the checkmark at left) so that others know that your problem has been solved without reading your comment.